# Finding a specific directional derivative

Tags: derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

I want to find all unit vectors $\textbf{v}$ such that the directional derivative of a function $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$ in the direction $\textbf{v}$ at $(1,\sqrt{3})$ is half the value of the directional derivative in the direction $\textbf{u}$ where $f$ increases most rapidly at the same point.

Here, we have $\nabla f(1,\sqrt{3})=(6,2\sqrt{3})$ and $|\nabla f(1,\sqrt{3})|=4\sqrt{3}$. Thus
$$
\textbf{u}=\frac{\nabla f(1,\sqrt{3})}{|\nabla f(1,\sqrt{3})|}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
and $D_{\textbf{u}}f(1,\sqrt{3})=4\sqrt{3}$.

**My approach:** We have
$$
D_{\textbf{v}}f(1,\sqrt{3})=\frac12D_{\textbf{u}}f(1,\sqrt{3}),
$$
and so, with $\textbf{v}=(a,b)$,
$$
(a,b)\cdot (6,2\sqrt{3})=\frac12|\nabla f(1,\sqrt{3})|=2\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow a=\frac{1-b}{\sqrt{3}}.
$$
Now, since we need $|\textbf{v}|=1$, we further impose
$$
\left(\frac{1-b}{\sqrt{3}} \right)^2+b^2=1\Rightarrow b=1\text{ or }b=-\frac12.
$$
Hence, we have two solutions, $\textbf{v}_1= \left(0   ,  1  \right)$ and $\textbf{v}_2= \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  ,-\frac12    \right)$.

Is this correct? I could multiply by a rotation matrix, knowing the angle, but I wanted to avoid that. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Well, one quicker way is to rotate without a matrix: recognize that $\cos(\pm\pi/3)=1/2$, and that $\nabla f$ makes an angle of $\pi/6$ with the $x$-axis, so the two sought-after unit vectors are at angles of $pi/2$ and $-\pi/6$. However, what you’ve done doesn’t seem all that long or complex to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's not. Thanks!